# what does broken formal languages mean?

Tags: computational-linguistics

I am learning Stanford CS224N: natural language processing with Deep Learning.

Chris said "a little bit broken formal languages" in [Lecture 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mT5DW2DKqHA&feature=youtu.be&t=665).

what does that mean? can any one give a concrete example to illustrate the difference between "formal languages" and "broken formal languages".

Comment: Could he have been talking about pseudocode? What was the context?

Comment: he is talking about human language for preparation of talking about natural language processing.

Comment: This is not jargon, it's just a common-English use of the word "broken". The full sentence is "*But for a lot of people [referring to computer scientists] you've, like, spent your life looking at formal languages and the impression is that, sort of, human languages are somehow a little bit broken formal languages.*" *Broken* isn't a technical term here, it just means "not working right"  - he's saying that natural language can be seen as a formal language that is "a little bit broken" i.e., a language that doesn't quite follow the rules a formal language is expected to.

Comment: The last edit by @fuDL added an entirely different question "which formal languages rule does human language break?" fu DL, if you have a different question, please ask it as a separate question instead of editing someone else's to add your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

agreed with Mark Beadles's comments.
Human language is a kind of broken formal languages because Human language doesn't quite follow the rules a formal language is expected to.