# which formal languages rule does human language break?

Tags: computational-linguistics

This [post](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/31153/24350) is discussing human language and formal languages.

According to the [professor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mT5DW2DKqHA&feature=youtu.be&t=665), human language is a kind of broken formal languages.

So, which formal languages rule does human language break?

Comment: It's a metaphor! He doesn't mean literally that human language is a broken version of some particular formal language.